# Package 2 WARs with different submodules

Tags: maven

I would like to package two WARs, which contain mutually exclusive low-level implementations. I have tried various approaches, and I get the nagging feeling I miss the obvious.

My project structure is structured in sub-modules:

```
app
  foo
    foo-highlevel
    foo-lowlevel1
    foo-lowlevel2
  bar
  webapp
```

The dependencies for WAR 1 should be:

```
webapp
\-foo-highlevel
  \-foo-lowlevel1
\-bar
  \-foo-highlevel
```

and accordingly for WAR 2:

```
webapp
\-foo-highlevel
  \-foo-lowlevel2
\-bar
  \-foo-highlevel
```

That is, I want to

- hide from bar which low level implementation is required by foo's highlevel implementation
- package only one lowlevel implementation. (Note: the lowlevel implementations include spring beans which get injected in foo-highlevel)

How can I achieve to package the two WARs accordingly?

Approaches I did try:

- Profiles: but they are not meant to create different artifacts for the same POM and it didn't work out anyway
- Multiple POMs: I could define two POMs for the webapps with a dependency for lowlevel1 or lowlevel2, respectively. But so far the dependency to foo-highlevel was sufficient in the webapp's POM, so I wonder if this really is the right place to decide on the low-level dependency.

Approaches I consider trying:

- Using maven's assembly plugin: but is this the right tool for this job?
- Using war overlays: maybe this is the right tool?

thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven's rule of thumb is "one artifact per pom", so I think your approach of "Multiple POMs" is the way to go. You could keep webapp as a parent-aggregator-project that defines the basic dependencies and then use 2 poms to build the `war`s that inherit from that top-level-pom and just specify the lowlevel-dependency.

Comment: thanks. I refactored webapp in an aggregate webapp pom, which contains webapp-lowlevel1 and webapp-lowlevel2, as well as webapp-common (for web.xml and shared source).